# Meaning of "leave on a full basis"

Tags: idioms, expressions

When I was reading News of Real Madrid - [Di Maria set to be released](http://www.transfermarketweb.com/?action=read&idsel=119482), I saw following sentence:

> Real Madrid management seem to have decided to let Di Maria leave on a full basis.

What does this mean(especially **full basis**)? Does that mean Di Maria will leave Real Madrid?

Comment: Can you clarify (in the question, preferably), _why_ you're confused about this sentence? Otherwise, we could needlessly be explaining words like _let_ and _leave_, when you're confused about _full basis_.

Comment: To answer this question, I think one might have to understand the ins and outs of how that football league is run. It sounds like a technical (contractual) term within that domain. For example, in American sports, we talk about _free agents, restricted free agents,_ etc.; outside that, the meanings of [those expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_agent) aren't discernible. I just Googled `"leave on a full basis"`; this question was at the top, but it was followed by news about soccer players. Evidently, it has to do with how players leave a club, and who pays what money to said player.

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, "full basis" is used in opposition to "temporary basis". In lot of pro sports you can let a player go to a foreign team on a temp basis, for various reasons:  strike cutting a season short, early season elimination, promotion of the sport (like Canadian hockey player doing a season or two in europe or european soccer player in the US), foreigner going back home to play for his national team...